# Convergence of a recursive function

Tags: recursion

I am trying to study the convergence of a function that is defined by recursion.
We want to find for which 'j' the difference between $ g_i^j $ and $ g_i^{j+1}  $ is equal or smaller than $10^{-3}$ .

I don’t know how to do  that, can we use FixedPoint for a function of two variables ? Or we necessarily have to use the loop While? 
Thanks

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_] := x^2;
g[i_Integer, 1] := g[i, 1] = f[i];
g[50, _] = g[0, _] = 0; (*initial and final condition*)
g[i_Integer, j_Integer] := g[i, j] = Max[0.5*(g[i - 1, j] + g[i + 1, j - 1]), f[i]];
```

I defined the function Gap for the difference of the two values as

```
Gap[i_,j_]:=Gap[i,j]=g[i,j+1]-g[i,j] ;
```

Comment: I need a little more info. (1) Do you want to find for which `j` the difference between two successive `g`'s is less than $10^{-3}$ *for all* `i` or *for some* `i`? (2) There are two inputs to `g` so how do you define the recursion? it is a recursion in `i` or a recursion on `j` or both? (It actually looks like there's backwards and forwards recursion on `i` somehow.)

Comment: It says to repeat the scan as many time as necessary so that all gaps between two successive values $g^j_i $ and $g^{j+1}_i$  is equal or smaller than $10^{-3}$ , so it is for all i. And for the recursion we see in the expression of $g$ that is  in $i$ and $j$